# Unable to implement ignore stale element as ignored_exceptions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

My code is working on the saved webpage and when I try it on the live website, it gives me

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
    oldelem = WebDriverWait(driver, 40,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@_tf='AC' and @bh='TF']"))
    )
    oldelem.clear()
```

Does it have to do with me not putting the driver to sleep? or quitting it? I actually have to clear the search bar so I can input more queries in it.

Comment: I don't think there's a constructor that takes ignore conditions...  but you wouldn't want to ignore that anyway.  This means that your webelement reference is stale.  (either the DOM is still updating, or it's updated completely since you retrieved the reference.)  If you ignored the exception you'd have a sort of rogue pointer to a DOM element?... You can either try/catch and if stale element is thrown you get the element again, or just add a standard sleep that is long enough for the DOM to be done updating before you retrieve the webelement reference.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is not something you can ignore. That message usually means the page has changed in some way but you are still using a previously-defined webelement. (and going from a stored page to a live one would count as changing the page from Selenium's point of view). Using "oldelem.clear()" does not reset the object. You need a new webelement.

Quick check: are you instantiating the webelement *after* the page loads? If not, try that.

Comment: I don't know how to reply to the other comment as I am new but you both were right, I just had to add time.sleep for .5 seconds and it started to work beautifully

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
 ignored_exceptions=[NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException]
```

use parameter ignored_exceptions and send an exception list to it.